# Is there a way to match serial numbers from two dataframes and add a list of Series (from rows) from df2 into a new column in df1 (Python, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As title, I am looking to generate a list (or other dtype) of all matching serial numbers from df2 and store them inside a new column in df1, such that when I pull up a record (product) from df1, I am able to find all the review scores for that product. Matched up by serial numbers.

```
data1 = { 'serialNumbers' : [1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5],
          'product' : ['a', 'b' , 'c', 'd', 'e']}
data2 = { 'reviewScore' : [5, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4], 
          'serialNumbers' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4],
          'otherData' : ['a', 'b' , 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b' , 'c', 'd', 'e','a']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

      df1
   serialNumbers product
0              1       a
1              2       b
2              3       c
3              4       d
4              5       e


      df2
    reviewScore  serialNumbers
0             5              1
1             1              1
2             4              1
3             1              1
4             5              3
5             2              4
6             4              4
7             3              2
8             1              3
9             3              3
10            4              4



      desired output:
   serialNumbers product                   reviewData
0              1       a  [5 : a , 1 : b, 4 : c, 1 : d]
1              2       b                        [3 : c]
2              3       c          [5 : e, 1 : d, 3 : e]
3              4       d          [2 : a, 4 : b, 4 : a]
4              5       e                             []
```

Comment: group by df2 by serial_num, then join the df's by serial_num. Does make sense?

Comment: Vaguely, any chance of some sample code or a link to where to find it? I have mildly misrepresented the question as I'll need the data from all columns in df2 row stored in the new column, updating now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `pd.merge`, `groupby`, and `agg`:

Let's break down the below:

- We are `left` merging **df1** with a grouped version of **df2**, which means we are keeping all information from **df1**, and attaching onto it the result of the `groupby`
- The `tolist()` within the `agg` functions , returns all the **reviewScores** per **serialNumber**

```
res = pd.merge(df1,(df2.groupby('serialNumbers').agg({'reviewScore':lambda x: x.tolist()})).reset_index(),how='left')
```

which prints:

```
   serialNumbers product   reviewScore
0              1       a  [5, 1, 4, 1]
1              2       b           [3]
2              3       c     [5, 1, 3]
3              4       d     [2, 4, 4]
4              5       e           NaN
```

**EDIT 1**:

Given your updated question, try this:

```
df2['temp'] = df2['reviewScore'].astype(str) + ' : ' + df2['otherData'].astype(str)
res = pd.merge(df1,(df2.groupby('serialNumbers').agg({'temp':lambda x: x.tolist()})).reset_index(),how='left')
```

which prints:

```
   serialNumbers product                          temp
0              1       a  [5 : a, 1 : b, 4 : c, 1 : d]
1              2       b                       [3 : c]
2              3       c         [5 : e, 1 : d, 3 : e]
3              4       d         [2 : a, 4 : b, 4 : a]
4              5       e                           NaN
```

Note that I am not sure that this is the most efficient way (or most pythonic way) to get this, but i think it can get you what you need.

**EDIT 2**:

```
df2['temp1'] = df2[['reviewScore','otherData']].values.tolist()
res = pd.merge(df1,(df2.groupby('serialNumbers').agg({'temp1':lambda x: x.tolist()})).reset_index(),how='left')

   serialNumbers product                             temp1
0              1       a  [[5, a], [1, b], [4, c], [1, d]]
1              2       b                          [[3, c]]
2              3       c          [[5, e], [1, d], [3, e]]
3              4       d          [[2, a], [4, b], [4, a]]
4              5       e                               NaN
```

Comment: This looks like a fantastic start, I've updated the question, I need to convert the rows from df2 into a Series or other dtype and store the whole thing in the list in the new column (sample code is not representative of actual data)

Comment: Please check the updated answer, I think this is what you need.

Comment: Much closer, the desired output I've posted wasn't supposed to just be a string with the data in, I'm looking for the new column to contain a list of objects generated from each row, containing all data from that row (with the exception of the serial number) is there a way to combine the row data into a single column (in a Series or List) and put that in the "temp" column, which then should in theory make your second line of code work and be exactly what I need

Thanks for this so far! It's very useful!

Comment: I should add that my dataset is very large, so if there's a way to achieve it without iterating over the entire dataframe, that'd be perfect, and if it's easier to do it and leave the serial numbers in, that's also not the end of the world, I can sort that out later down the line

Comment: You could get the 'temp' column in a list with ```df2['temp1'] = df2[['reviewScore','otherData']].values.tolist()```, but then the result wont' be exactly as you want it i.e. [5 : a] will be [5,a].

Comment: That's perfect, I'm not fussed about the (5:a) to [5,a] bit, I'd just typed that representation out by hand. is there anyway to do the "['reviewScore','otherData']" bit such that it selects the data from all rows instead of having to hardcode the column headers?

Comment: You mean because you have many columns, instead of creating a new column with just the values of "['reviewScore','otherData']", to create a new column with all the available columns in the dataframe? and you don't want to have to type all of them 1 by 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227107/discussion-between-david-pinchen-and-sophods).